# Particular eigenmatrix form derivation

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to get a eigenmatrix of the form:

$
\Lambda =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1}} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_2}} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dots & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}
\end{bmatrix}
$

Though, I am having issues deriving it. Best I can think of is to have

$
Ax = \lambda_i x \implies \frac{1}{\lambda_i}Ax = x.
$

Then, from this, to perform a decomposition of the left hand side to get the desired eigenmatrix $\Lambda$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Trying to get it out of what? Are you trying to find a matrix whose eigenvalues are the diagonal of your $\Lambda$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of some given matrix $A$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Sorry if that wasn't clear. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: What restrictions do you have? Certainly that $\Lambda$ is one such matrix, but would you rather it be some simpler expression in terms of $A$?

Comment: No restrictions as far as I know. I just want to see a derivation of $\Lambda$. I am aware how to achieve a simpler eigenmatrix. Some document I am looking at has such a eigenmatrix and I am trying to understand where it comes from.

Comment: I don't understand what "derivation" is supposed to mean, though. Those are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1/2}$, which can be useful in certain contexts, but we don't have enough context to really help you see why that should be a useful object.

Comment: I guess I am unaware of the particular context. Though, you mentioning that these are the eigenvalues of $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ helps. What I meant by derivation would be to, starting from the standard definition of $Ax = \lambda x$ to get to a eigenmatrix of this form.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do that like there is for the case of *integer* powers of the eigenvalues, where one can easily define $A^k$ by multiplication of $A$ or $A^{-1}$. Fractional powers are only defined implicitly by the power itself, and are usually explicitly defined in terms of the eigenvalues themselves.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll have to derive some context to make sense of it I suppose. Thanks.